# How to use a Java class variable in a JSP

Tags: jsp

I am using Struts2 and I need to access the Java class variable on the JSP page. How can I do it? In the Java variable I have appended script and HTML. I need to render that HTML and scripts. In `textField` I can easily access the variable `commonString`. But I'm unable to render it as HTML.

Variable in java page:

```
 StringBuilder data=new StringBuilder().append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"       src=\"").append("js/crossfilter.v1.js").append("\"></script>");
         data.append("js/bubble.js").append("\"></script>").append("<body onload='bubble").append("<%=request.getAttribute("+commonString+")%>)").append("'>").append("</body>");
         String commonString=data.toString();
```

HTML page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ page import="com.helical.efw.view.StageExecution" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
 prefix="c" %>
 <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <style>

         text {
     font: 10px sans-serif;
      }
      </style>
        <%!
         String ss;
       %>
       </head>
     <s:textfield name="commonString" value="%{commonString}"></s:textfield>
     </html>
```

Comment: Please show the class and its variable and how you sent that to JSP.

Comment: Do you mean you want to print the value of the `data` variable in your JSP page?

Comment: where you want to render your html content in jsp page ?

Comment: Are you trying to put JSP code (e.g. your `<%=request.getAttribute("+commonString+")%>)`) in a variable and have that code run when the page is rendered? AFAIK that's not possible

Comment: @Yagnesh :before <head> tag in jsp

Comment: What you should do it put all the JSP/HTML code directly in your JSP page

Comment: @Martin Wilson:Yes I can do it but my requirement is like that to generalize something

Comment: you can add HTML content in JSP but you cant render your HTML content in JSP like this.